# How can I check if my python object is a number?

Tags: python, types, numbers

In Java the numeric types all descend from Number so I would use

```
(x instanceof Number).
```

What is the python equivalent?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, the other one is a very specific case of this question (check if something is a number in a vector), and most voted answers really relate to that detail.

Comment: Multiply x by zero.  if the results is anything other than zero then x is not a number see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44418960/3419693

Answer (score 339, accepted):

Test if your variable is an instance of [`numbers.Number`](https://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number):

```
>>> import numbers
>>> import decimal
>>> [isinstance(x, numbers.Number) for x in (0, 0.0, 0j, decimal.Decimal(0))]
[True, True, True, True]
```

This uses [ABCs](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class) and will work for all built-in number-like classes, and also for all third-party classes if they are worth their salt (registered as subclasses of the `Number` ABC).

However, in many cases you shouldn't worry about checking types manually - Python is [duck typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and mixing somewhat compatible types usually works, yet it will barf an error message when some operation doesn't make sense (`4 - "1"`), so manually checking this is rarely really needed. It's just a bonus. You can add it when finishing a module to avoid pestering others with implementation details.

This works [starting with Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3141-a-type-hierarchy-for-numbers). On older versions you're pretty much limited to checking for a few hardcoded types.

Comment: This gives a false positive when you pass it a boolean: `isinstance(True, numbers.Number)` returns `True` even though `True` is clearly not a number.

Comment: @AlexKahn In Python, booleans are practically numbers: `bool` inherits from `int`, `abs(True) == 1`, `"foo" * False == ""`, `sum([True, False, True]) == 2`, `"%f" % True == "1.0"`, and so on.

Comment: Frustratingly, ```isinstance(float('nan'), numbers.Number)``` returns ```True```

Comment: to exclude boolean you can use the following.
   `isinstance(x, numbers.Number) and not isinstance(x, bool)`

Comment: You can also use `type(x) in (int, float, complex)` to check if `x` is directly one of those types instead of an instance of them

Comment: @Break I think you mean "to check if x is an instance of one of these types directly instead of an instance of a child type".

Answer (score 241):

Python 3:

```
isinstance(x, (int, float, complex)) and not isinstance(x, bool)
```

Python 2:

```
isinstance(x, (int, long, float, complex)) and not isinstance(x, bool)
```

Note that this answer works incorrectly for Numpy objects.

Comment: Thanks, this is what ended up working for me in Jython (which is python 2.5 so it doesn't have the 'numbers' package).  And yes I have a real reason to break duck typing; I need to treat strings and numbers differently.

Comment: `isinstance(Decimal(10), (int, long, float, complex))` gives `False`. -1

Comment: This also doesn't work if `x` is a boolean. `isinstance(True, (int, long, float, complex))` returns `True`.

Comment: @AlexKahn `isinstance(True, numbers.Number)` or `isinstance(False, numbers.Number)` also returns True.

Comment: `True` and `False` are integers in python (boolean is a subclass of int). Do another check: `type(True) is boolean`

Comment: Short note: `float('nan')` might be considered non-numeric, but this will - of course - still return `True`.

Comment: numpy gotcha: `isinstance(np.int64, int) == False`

Answer (score 63):

Use `Number` from the `numbers` module to test `isinstance(n, Number)` (available since 2.6).

```
isinstance(n, numbers.Number)
```

Here it is in action with various kinds of numbers and one non-number:

```
>>> from numbers import Number
... from decimal import Decimal
... from fractions import Fraction
... for n in [2, 2.0, Decimal('2.0'), complex(2,0), Fraction(2,1), '2']:
...     print '%15s %s' % (n.__repr__(), isinstance(n, Number))
              2 True
            2.0 True
 Decimal('2.0') True
         (2+0j) True
 Fraction(2, 1) True
            '2' False
```

This is, of course, contrary to duck typing. If you are more concerned about how an object acts rather than what it is, perform your operations as if you have a number and use exceptions to tell you otherwise.

Comment: The "see if there's an exception" strategy is often ineffective. Python is a little aggressive in allowing arithmetic-type operations on all sorts of non-arithmetic things - so just because an object allows `+` or `*` doesn't mean it's anything at all like a number.

Answer (score -2):

Sure you can use `isinstance`, but be aware that this is not how Python works. Python is a duck typed language. You should not explicitly check your types. A `TypeError` will be raised if the incorrect type was passed.

So just assume it is an `int`. Don't bother checking.

Comment: as noted before, the whole point of duck-typing is to allow method overloading and method polymorphism in the same class.

Comment: Duck-typing is not always the way to go. Sometimes it's better to have a small check paragraph at the start of a function and fail or fix inputs, rather than encase your whole code in `try-except` which makes the whole thing hard to read.

Answer (score -13):

That's not really how python works. Just use it like you would a number, and if someone passes you something that's not a number, fail. It's the programmer's responsibility to pass in the correct types.

Comment: Specifically, use `except TypeError:`. Exceptions are relatively expensive, however.

Comment: ...but only if they are triggered. In the "normal" case they are cheaper than an `if` statement.

Comment: not always quite so simple, sometimes both types support the interface but you want to handle them differently. Consider a reduce function that should add numbers but not concatenate strings.

Comment: This answer is assuming the most naive scripts, and doesn't consider complex cases.  As Rob says, there are legitimate needs for handling a number differently than a string.  There are also many cases where a custom class needs to behave one way when multiplied by a number and a different way when multiplied by an instance of itself.  You might implement a matrix class in such a way.

Comment: @Nerdmaster: Python specifically doesn't support operator overloading.

Comment: @Falmarri it absolutely does... http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: Defensive programming is a necessity especially when you are using those values to perform data manipulation operations in, for instance, a database. Dynamic languages are fantastic, but sometimes you need your guarantees.