# Python: True if variable is integer or float

Tags: python, variables, methods, integer, int

I am trying to write a small program from a book assignment, but I am having trouble with detecting if the user's input is a `int/float` (increment to the total) or `string` (`return error`). I tried using **.isdigit()** on the **add_to_total** variable but when I type in a float, it skips straight to the else code block. I have tried searching on the internet but can't find a clear answer. Here is my code:

```
total = 0
print("Welcome to the receipt program!")

while True:
    add_to_total = raw_input("Enter the value for the seat ['q' to quit]: ")
    if add_to_total == 'q':
        print("*****")
        print "Total: $%s" % total
        break
    if add_to_total.isdigit(): #Don't know how to detect if variable is int or float at the same time.
        add_to_total = float(add_to_total)
        total += add_to_total
    else:
        print "I'm sorry, but '%s' isn't valid. Please try again." % add_to_total
```

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use exceptions to catch user inputs that can not be summed up. Switch from testing any user input, to just guard the mathematical operation to sum up receipts.

```py
total = 0
print("Welcome to the receipt program!")

while True:
    add_to_total = raw_input("Enter the value for the seat ['q' to quit]: ")
    if add_to_total == 'q':
        break
    try:
        total += float(add_to_total)
    except ValueError:
        print "I'm sorry, but '%s' isn't valid. Please try again." % add_to_total
print("*****")
print "Total: $%s" % total
```

Comment: thank you, it worked. I think i tried using this method before but put it somewhere wrong. Accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use the `try... except` approach:

```
try:
    add_to_total = float(add_to_total)
except ValueError:
    print "I'm sorry, but '%s' isn't valid. Please try again." % add_to_total
else:
    total += add_to_total
```

Remember: [it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Answer (score 4):

Very close to an old entry : [How can I check if my python object is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187185/how-can-i-check-if-my-python-object-is-a-number). The answer is:

```
isinstance(x, (int, long, float, complex))
```

Comment: The OP is checking if a string can be converted to an number, not if an an existing object has a numeric type.