# Why is not 'decimal.Decimal(1)' an instance of 'numbers.Real'?

Tags: python, numbers, decimal, isinstance

I try to check if a variable is an instance of a number of any type (`int`, `float`, `Fraction`, `Decimal`, etc.).

I cam accross this question and its answer: [How to properly use python's isinstance() to check if a variable is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4187266/2291710)

However, I would like to exclude complex numbers such as `1j`.

The class [`numbers.Real`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/numbers.html#numbers.Real) looked perfect but it returns `False` for [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) numbers...

```
from numbers Real
from decimal import Decimal

print(isinstance(Decimal(1), Real))
# False
```

In contradiction, it works fine with [`Fraction(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) for example.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/numbers.html#numbers.Real) describes some operations which should work with the number, I tested them without any error on a decimal instance.
Decimal objects cannot contains complex numbers moreover.

So, why `isinstance(Decimal(1), Real)` would return `False`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/numbers.html#the-numeric-tower

Comment: @TomDalton I read it, but still I dont understand. `[isinstance(Decimal(1), t) for t in [Number, Complex, Real, Rational, Integral]]` returns `[True, False, False, False, False]`. If a `Decimal` is a `Number`, why it is not any of its sublasses?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, I found the answer directly in the source code of [`cpython/numbers.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9e78dc25179a492550dc602e47e7f4d24e3c89a3/Lib/numbers.py#L24-L30):

```
## Notes on Decimal
## ----------------
## Decimal has all of the methods specified by the Real abc, but it should
## not be registered as a Real because decimals do not interoperate with
## binary floats (i.e.  Decimal('3.14') + 2.71828 is undefined).  But,
## abstract reals are expected to interoperate (i.e. R1 + R2 should be
## expected to work if R1 and R2 are both Reals).
```

Indeed, adding `Decimal` to `float` would raise a `TypeError`.

In my point of view, it violates the principle of least astonishment, but it does not matter much.

As a workaround, I use:

```
import numbers
import decimal

Real = (numbers.Real, decimal.Decimal)

print(isinstance(decimal.Decimal(1), Real))
# True
```