# Python comparison ignoring nan

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, nan, equality

While `nan == nan` is always `False`, in many cases people want to treat them as equal, and this is enshrined in [`pandas.DataFrame.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html):

> NaNs in the same location are considered equal.

Of course, I can write

```
def equalp(x, y):
    return (x == y) or (math.isnan(x) and math.isnan(y))
```

However, this will fail on containers like `[float("nan")]` and `isnan` barfs on non-numbers (so [the complexity increases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4187185/850781)).

So, what do people do to compare complex Python objects which may contain `nan`?

**PS**. Motivation: when comparing two rows in a pandas `DataFrame`, I would [convert them into `dict`s](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and compare dicts element-wise.

**PPS**. When I say "*compare*", I am thinking [`diff`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/diff/), not [`equalp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equalp.htm).

Comment: If you're asking what people do... then the answer is, they usually don't. Having non-scalar/object columns is usually considered bad form, and introduces a lot of headaches you could otherwise avoid by flattening your data a bit. It's also a less-performant option.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think they mean when outside of pandas containers, like lists with `float('nan')` in them.

Comment: I think *most* people just accept that Python knows best and `NaN != NaN`. Or try to avoid having NaN altogether.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, are your lists always integers or floats?

Comment: Yeah, at this point, you might as well use something like `NAN = object()` then replace `float('nan')` with `NAN`

Comment: @sds why would you do this? "Motivation: when comparing two rows in a pandas DataFrame, I would convert them into dicts and compare dicts element-wise."

Comment: @sds: Like juanpa said, do you really need the dict (maybe for other operations)? There is also `df.as_matrix()` which would make things easier.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: how would you compare two rows or length 400?

Comment: @sds `df.iloc[1,:].equals(df.iloc[2:])`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: okay, I got `False`. How do I get the list of columns where the rows are different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose you have a data-frame with `nan` values:

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, (10, 10)).astype(float), columns=["c%d"%d for d in range(10)])

In [10]: df.where(np.random.randint(0,2, df.shape).astype(bool), np.nan, inplace=True)

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
     c0    c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6    c7   c8    c9
0   NaN   6.0  14.0   NaN   5.0   NaN   2.0  12.0  3.0   7.0
1   NaN   6.0   5.0  17.0   NaN   NaN  13.0   NaN  NaN   NaN
2   NaN  17.0   NaN   8.0   6.0   NaN   NaN  13.0  NaN   NaN
3   3.0   NaN   NaN  15.0   NaN   8.0   3.0   NaN  3.0   NaN
4   7.0   8.0   7.0   NaN   9.0  19.0   NaN   0.0  NaN  11.0
5   NaN   NaN  14.0   2.0   NaN   NaN   0.0   NaN  NaN   8.0
6   3.0  13.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  12.0  3.0   NaN
7  13.0  14.0   NaN   5.0  13.0   NaN  18.0   6.0  NaN   5.0
8   3.0   9.0  14.0  19.0  11.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   5.0
9   3.0  17.0   NaN   NaN   0.0   NaN  11.0   NaN  NaN   0.0
```

And you want to compare rows, say, row 0 and 8. Then just use `fillna` and do vectorized comparison:

```
In [12]: df.iloc[0,:].fillna(0) != df.iloc[8,:].fillna(0)
Out[12]:
c0     True
c1     True
c2    False
c3     True
c4     True
c5    False
c6     True
c7     True
c8     True
c9     True
dtype: bool
```

You can use the resulting boolean array to index into the columns, if you just want to know which columns are different:

```
In [14]: df.columns[df.iloc[0,:].fillna(0) != df.iloc[8,:].fillna(0)]
Out[14]: Index(['c0', 'c1', 'c3', 'c4', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: This gives you False for entries that were NaN in one column and 0 in the other

Comment: @DiegoFMedina yes, totally. I was being too clever for my own good. This will only work if you know a good value to use for a fillvalue (due to the nature of your data). Alternatively, you can do something like: `row0 = df.iloc[0, :]; row8 = df.iloc[8,:];` then `(row0 == row8) | (row0.isnull() & row8.isnull())` to find the columns that are equal treating NaNs as equal

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have array-data or can at least convert to a numpy array?

One way is to mask all the nans using a `numpy.ma`array, then comparing the arrays. So your starting situation would be sth. like this

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
arr1 = ma.array([3,4,6,np.nan,2])
arr2 = ma.array([3,4,6,np.nan,2])

print arr1 == arr2
print ma.all(arr1==arr2)

>>> [ True  True  True False  True]
>>> False  # <-- you want this to show True
```

Solution:

```
arr1[np.isnan(arr1)] = ma.masked
arr2[np.isnan(arr2)] = ma.masked

print arr1 == arr2
print ma.all(arr1==arr2)

>>> [True True True -- True]
>>> True
```

Comment: this is not what I am looking for, please see motivation in PS

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that recurses into a data structure replacing `nan` values with a unique string. I wrote this for a unit test that compares data structures that may contain `nan`.

It's only designed for data structures made of `dict` and `list`, but it's easy to see how to expand it.

```py
from math import isnan
from uuid import uuid4
from typing import Union

NAN_REPLACEMENT = f"THIS_WAS_A_NAN{uuid4()}"

def replace_nans(data_structure: Union[dict, list]) -> Union[dict, list]:
    if isinstance(data_structure, dict):
        iterme = data_structure.items()
    elif isinstance(data_structure, list):
        iterme = enumerate(data_structure)
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            "replace_nans should only be called on structures made of dicts and lists"
        )

    for key, value in iterme:
        if isinstance(value, float) and isnan(value):
            data_structure[key] = NAN_REPLACEMENT
        elif isinstance(value, dict) or isinstance(value, list):
            data_structure[key] = replace_nans(data_structure[key])
    return data_structure
```