# Pandas: nan->None

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, nan

[`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) converts `nan` to `nan` and `null` to `None`. As explained in [Python comparison ignoring nan](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48452933/850781) this is sometimes suboptimal.

Is there a way to convert all `nan`s to `None`? (either in `pandas` or later on in Python)

E.g.,

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,None],"b":[None,"foo"]})
>>> df
     a     b
0  1.0  None
1  NaN   foo
>>> df.to_dict()
{'a': {0: 1.0, 1: nan}, 'b': {0: None, 1: 'foo'}}
```

I want

```
{'a': {0: 1.0, 1: None}, 'b': {0: None, 1: 'foo'}}
```

instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,None],"b":[None,"foo"]})
df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
Out[850]: 
      a     b
0     1  None
1  None   foo
df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None).to_dict()
Out[851]: {'a': {0: 1.0, 1: None}, 'b': {0: None, 1: 'foo'}}
```

Comment: I'll note that this does the same thing, converts every column to an object type, just that it does it in two steps.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep, you are right , almost the same :-)

Comment: Just mentioning that since OP seems to think this is converting the data to string (which isn't the case!).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: this is different from what you suggested because it works on the externally generated `DataFrame`, as opposed to creating a generic DF from scratch.

Comment: @sds I am aware of what it does. My point in my previous comment was that the end result is the same (a generic dataframe), not a dataframe of strings like you initially surmised. I was only addressing your misconception, nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

Initialise as an object DataFrame (at your peril...):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,None],"b":[None,"foo"]}, dtype=object)    
df

      a     b
0     1  None
1  None   foo
```

In the first column, pandas attempts to infer the dtype, and guesses float. You can prevent that by forcing it to remain `object` thereby suppressing any type of conversion at all.

Comment: This is cheating. I have _numeric_ columns in the `DataFrame`, and converting it to string loses information.

Comment: @sds No, there is no string conversion taking place.

Comment: Each column is initialised as column of python objects. Pandas no longer makes assumptions about what its content is, and falls back to slow methods of operating on it.

Comment: I had a feeling though that `df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,None],"b":[None,"foo"]})` was an MCVE to give a starting DF to play with. In reality, if you're at the end of a chain of processes, does it make sense to convert your whole resulting DF to `object` before `to_dict()`?

Comment: @sds `object != str`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I've just seen your comment on the other answer so I'm probably wrong here.

Comment: @roganjosh It usually doesn't make sense converting any dataframe to object except in the rarest of cases. OP seems to have a good reason for wanting to do so, so I'm not getting in their way here...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No, what I meant by my very last comment is I missed something. `df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None).to_dict()` looks the business, but you stated it's converting to `object` type in two steps. So your answer, on the surface, _does_ look like a cheat to me because you alter the DF at creation but ultimately it doesn't matter. +1 for reshaping my thinking :)

Comment: @roganjosh Cheers, as long as you call `pd.DataFrame` _somewhere_, this works :D