# Testing dataclass objects for equality with a NaN attribute

Tags: python, nan, python-dataclasses

Is there an easy way handle NaN attributes when testing dataclass objects for equality? Here is my minimal example:

```
import pickle
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class MyClass:
    a: float


mc = MyClass(float('nan'))

# Serialize and deserialize
mc2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(mc))

assert mc2 == mc  # E   assert MyClass(a=nan) == MyClass(a=nan)
```

Current errors as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "???.py", line 15, in <module>
    assert mc2 == mc  # E   assert MyClass(a=nan) == MyClass(a=nan)
AssertionError
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python comparison ignoring nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452933/python-comparison-ignoring-nan)

Comment: No, I'm interested in the selected answer wrt Dataclasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to override the custom equality logic for a float then you're starting to move away from what dataclasses were designed for. It's only a small move, so dataclasses can still give you a bit of flexibility.

Dataclasses will honour any custom logic you write for your class. So you are completely free to write your own implementation of `__eq__` that does what you want. For instance:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from math import isnan

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    a: float
    b: float

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (
            self.__class__ is other.__class__
            and self.a == other.a
            and (
                self.b == other.b
                or (isnan(self.b) and isnan(other.b))
            )
        )

same_1 = MyClass(1, 2.5)
same_2 = MyClass(1, 2.5)
different_a = MyClass(2, 2.5)
different_b = MyClass(1, 3.0)
nan_1 = MyClass(1, float('nan'))
nan_2 = MyClass(1, float('nan'))

assert nan_1 is not nan_2 and nan_1.b is not nan_2.b, \
    "check equality operator cannot be short-circuited due to object identity"
assert nan_1 == nan_2, "equal when both bs are nan"

assert same_1 == same_1, "same object"
assert same_1 == same_2, "different object, but equal attributes"
assert same_1 != different_a, "different a attribute"
assert same_1 != different_b, "different b attribute"
assert same_1 != nan_1, "preserve nan inequality with other numbers"
```

You could play about with meta programming to reduce the amount of code in your class. However, if you provide a custom equality operator then your code will remain clear. It will be easy to see the reason you have implemented a custom equality operator, and how it works. Plus it will be marginally more efficient -- no transient object creation or additional instance checks required.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know if this is the easiest or most straightforward way, but I'd start by creating a custom sub-class of the `float` type, which implements an equality or `__eq__` method which implements the desired logic. So, something along the lines of this:

```py
from math import isnan

class FloatWithEq(float):

    def __eq__(self, other, __super_eq__=float.__eq__):
        if isnan(other) and isnan(self):
            return True

        # noinspection PyArgumentList
        return __super_eq__(self, other)
```

Then, this can be used as the field type of `a` in the class as normal. Note that I've also went ahead and turned `a` into a *field property*, just so that it's a little easier to pass in to the constructor method: for example, you can pass in either a `FloatWithEq` or even a `float` or `str` type, which will automatically be converted to our custom type, as shown below.

```py
from __future__ import annotations  # not needed in PY 3.10+

import pickle
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class MyClass:
    a: FloatWithEq | float | str
    _a: FloatWithEq = field(init=False, repr=False)

    @property
    def a(self) -> FloatWithEq:
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, a: FloatWithEq | float | str) -> None:
        self._a = a if isinstance(a, FloatWithEq) else FloatWithEq(a)


mc = MyClass(float('nan'))

# Serialize and deserialize
mc2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(mc))

assert mc2 == mc  # it works!
```

An *even better* approach, for code reusability and to simplify the above usage, is to make use of a newer concept called [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#complete-practical-example), and then define a *descriptor class* as follows:

```py
class FloatWithEqDescriptor:

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        setattr(
            obj, self.private_name,
            val if isinstance(val, FloatWithEq) else FloatWithEq(val)
        )
```

And then this can be used after a similar fashion, such as below:

```
from __future__ import annotations  # not needed in PY 3.10+

import pickle
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    a: FloatWithEq | float | int | str = FloatWithEqDescriptor()
    b: FloatWithEq | float | int | str = FloatWithEqDescriptor()


mc = MyClass(float('nan'), 1.23)

# Serialize and deserialize
mc2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(mc))

assert mc2 == mc  # it works!
```

Answer (score 0):

From python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons):

> The not-a-number values float('NaN') and decimal.Decimal('NaN') are
> special. Any ordered comparison of a number to a not-a-number value is
> false. **A counter-intuitive implication is that not-a-number values are
> not equal to themselves**. For example, if x = float('NaN'), 3 < x, x <
> 3 and x == x are all false, while x != x is true. This behavior is
> compliant with IEEE 754.

That is a design feature of python. And, indeed, two not-number *whatever* are not necessarily the same *thing*.
I would use something like

```
from math import isnan
assert assert all((isnan(mc2.a),isnan(mc.a)))
```

Though, by doing so you're not comparing the class data.
Otherwise, you should implement a custom class data as the one suggested by rv.kvteck, or you can use a `None` type instead of `float('nan')` when needed:

```
myNan = None # or whatever you want
mc = MyClass(myNan)

# Serialize and deserialize
mc2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(mc))

assert mc==mc2
```