# __add__ to support addition of different types?

Tags: python, overloading, addition

Would be very easy to solve had python been a static programming language that supported overloading. I am making a class called Complex which is a representation of complex numbers (I know python has its own, but i want to make one myself), where a is the real number and b is the imaginary (`Complex(a, b)`). It should support adding Complex instances together (`Complex(2, 4) + Complex(4, 5) = Complex(6, 9)`), as well as adding an integer (`Complex(2, 3) + 4 = Complex(6, 3)`). However, due to the nature of python...

```py
__add__(self, other):
```

...I have to choose which the class will support, because it won't recognize types at compile-time, as well as not supporting overloading of functions. What is the best solution? Do I have to write an if statement in relation to the datatype of the `other` parameter?

Comment: If you want to support adding objects of different types, the nicest option in my opinion is to use [single dispatcher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch), although it might be a bit of an overkill here on second thought. Try it out and see what do you prefer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is check for the thing being of instance Complex, and if not, turn it into one, like so:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Complex):
        # do addition
    else:
        return self + Complex(other, 0)
```

That of course does not eliminate type checking, but it reuses whatever you are doing in `__init__` (which is probably checking if input is int or float).

If at the moment you do not do type checking in init, it is probably a good idea, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4187220/728795) looks reasonable, excepting built-in complex type.

Answer (score 1):

## Mixed-types operations

The `numbers` module in Python can be used to implement you own number classes. Among other things it [allows to correctly implement mixed-types operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#implementing-the-arithmetic-operations) using `__add__` and `__radd__`

#### Example

```
import numbers

class Complex:
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(self, Complex):
            ...
        elif isinstance(other, numbers.Real):
            ...
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other
```

## Implemention new number types

If you want to implement a number class which works along with Python built-in number types, you can implement your own `Complex` class by subclassing the abstract base class [`numbers.Complex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Complex).

This abstract base class will enforce the implementation of the needed methods `__abs__`, `__add__`, `__complex__`, `__eq__`, `__mul__`, `__neg__`, `__pos__`, `__pow__`, `__radd__`, `__rmul__`, `__rpow__`, `__rtruediv__`, `__truediv__`, `conjugate`, `imag` and `real`.

Answer (score 1):

Use isinstance to check if it's the same Type if not assum it's any type of number:

```py
  def __add__(self, other):
       # it's the same class
       if isinstance(other, Complex):
            # and you should return the same class 
            # if anyone extend your class SomeClass(Complex): you should return SomeClass not Complex Object
            return self.__class__(self.a + other.a, self.b + other.b)

       # assuming is any type of number
       try:
         return self.__class__(int(self.a + other), self.b)
       except TypeError:
         # change the error message
         raise TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for +: '%s' and '%s'" % (self.__class__, other.__class__)
```

Comment: That's `__iadd__`, the in-place add. Depending on whether Complex numbers are supposed to be modifiable in place, or not, you may or may not want that one.

Comment: Yes I forget that __add__ should return an object of the same Class ^^

Comment: when returning make sure to return an object of the same class not Complex class

Comment: If you want Complex to be sub-class-able without forcing the subclass to provide its own functions, yes, use `self.__class__` to construct the return value.

Comment: It's always recommended To use this technique it's safer.

Answer (score 1):

There is not necessarily a *best* solution.  In this particular case, though:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    c = make_complex(other)
    return Complex(self.real + c.real, self.imag + real.imag)
```

is probably the way to go (though I'm making lots of assumptions about your `Complex` class here).  If `other` is already `Complex`, the `make_complex` function returns it.  If not, it tries its best to convert (e.g., to turn a real-only into a complex pair by constructing a complex with a zero imaginary part).  If that fails, it raises some suitable exception.

This `make_complex` is also suitable in the constructor for `Complex`, so that you can replace parts of:

```
e = Complex(1.718, 0) # e (well, not very exactly)
i = Complex(0, 1) # sqrt(-1)
pi = Complex(3.14, 0) # pi
# you know what to do next
```

with:

```
e = Complex(1.718)
pi = make_complex(3.14)
```

for instance.  (You can just use the `Complex` constructor to do all the work, using `isinstance()` to check the argument types as appropriate.)

Note that since complex addition is commutative you may wish to implement `__radd__` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your notes about the difference between `__add__` and `__iadd__`

Answer (score -1):

What's the problem here?

You can always check the type of a python object:

```
if type(other) != type(self):
    # raise some error
# do addition
return
```