# easier way to do this IF statement to differentiate type of variable passed to function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Still very new to python. I have refactored a piece of coe and extracted the following code to a new method. It works fine but in search of more pythonic ways I feel the IF clauses are maybe clumsy. Essentially the function may be passed either a str or a number as the variable 'second_option' As a result there is a subtle difference to the next line.

I tried a conditional assignment but it seemed to get upset over the data frame elements of this.

```
    def create_crossover_data(self, indicator, second_option, market_data):
    if type(second_option) == str:
        market_data['position'] = market_data[indicator] > market_data[second_option]

    else:
        if type(second_option) == int or float:
            market_data['position'] = market_data[indicator] > second_option
        
    market_data['pre_position'] = market_data['position'].shift(1)
    market_data.dropna(inplace=True)  # dropping the NaN values
    market_data['crossover'] = np.where(market_data['position'] == market_data['pre_position'], False, True)
    market_data.drop(columns=['position', 'pre_position'])
```

Comment: Note also: `if type(second_option) == int or float:` is likely not working how you think it is. See [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way in Python to check the type of a variable: `isinstance()`.

Here you have a couple of options to rewrite your code:

```
def create_crossover_data(self, indicator, second_option, market_data):
    if isinstance(second_option, str):
        threshold = market_data[second_option]
    if isinstance(second_option, (int, float)):
        threshold = second_option

    market_data['position'] = market_data[indicator] > threshold
```

The next one looks simpler but makes the assumption `second_option` can only be a number or a string, and that might not be true, so I would add some control to that:

```
def create_crossover_data(self, indicator, second_option, market_data):
    market_data['position'] = market_data[indicator] > second_option if isinstance(second_option, (int, float)) else market_data[second_option]
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll use the first option as it just reads better.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, in python, it is prudent to use `isinstance` instead of `type`. Type only checks that the exact type matches while `isinstance` checks if our object in question inherits from the given type.

Assuming your second if statement is trying to determine if the variable in question is a number you can use. This method: [How can I check if my python object is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187185/how-can-i-check-if-my-python-object-is-a-number)

Which in your case would be

```
else:
        if isinstance(second_option,numbers.Number):
            market_data['position'] = market_data[indicator] > second_option
```

Comment: Thanks. I will now go through all my code and remove type(). Learn a new thing every day  here.

Answer (score 0):

Also new to this, but I see nothing except else if -> elif