# Searching for a string character in a list with different types of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list consisting of different types of values - that is, ints and strings. I want to use a loop to find character indexes that are not numbers.

```
#for a list
list = [2, 3, 4, '*', 2, '^', '+']
#Output should look like this
3, 5, 6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Find in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

Comment: See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9542768/15032126) in the suggested duplicate, the last part _Finding the location of an item_. You'll want to check for type instead of equality.

Comment: Don't use `list` as name. It overwrites the name of the built-in class.

Comment: What about a character that is a number (e.g. str `'2'` instead of int `2`)?

Answer (score 2):

For ints only, you can do something like

```py
[idx for idx,val in enumerate(lst) if type(val) != int]
```

Later, you said "not numbers". For that, there are few options - one uses the answer here to check if a value is a number: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4187266/2506943

```py
import numbers
[idx for idx,val in enumerate(lst)  if not isinstance(val, numbers.Number)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try list comprehension using the built-in function `type`

```
lst = [2, 3, 4, '*', 2, '^', '+']
out = [idx for idx,val in enumerate(lst) if type(val) == str]  # -> [3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `isinstance` to check if current item is string.

```
lst = [2, 3, 4, '*', 2, '^', '+']
result = []

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if isinstance(lst[i], str):
        result.append(i)
# or use list comprehension
result = [i for i in range(len(lst)) if isinstance(lst[i], str)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
listA = [2, 3, 4, '*', 2, '^', '+']
res=set(listA)
for i in res:
    if str(i).isalnum()!=True:
        print(listA.index(i))
```

you can simply use `listA` instead of converting that to set *to remove duplicates*.

Comment: Even without using `set` this will miss the duplicates, which is likely not what the OP wants.