# Mixed type list comprehensions in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

im trying to filter a list for numbers greater than a certain value whilst keeping any strings in the list.

Id like to acheive this without a loop, so preferably a list comprehension. So far i have this, i know why its not working but im unsure how to get it to work

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 'hello', 'world']
filtered_list = [x for x in my_list if (isinstance(x,str)) | ((isinstance(x,int))&(x>2))]
```

expected result:

```
[3, 'hello', 'world']
```

Actual result:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: First thing: use logical (`and`, `or`), not bitwise (`&`, `|`) operators.

Comment: Should be `filtered_list = [x for x in my_list if (isinstance(x, str)) or ((isinstance(x, int)) and (x > 2))]`

Comment: List comprehension is still a loop

Comment: You can't do this without a loop. If you see either while or for in your code (even within a comprehension) then you have a loop. Is it guaranteed that your input list only contains either ints or strings?

Comment: ok thanks for the technical clarification, it seems others were still able to understand the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use logical operators. You can also reduce it to one `isinstance` using `not`

```
filtered_list = [x for x in my_list if not (isinstance(x, int) and x < 3)]
print(filtered_list) # [3, 'hello', 'world']
```

Comment: @SashSinha the OP's example contains only numbers and strings. I would definitely allow this if I saw it in a code review; there currently is no need for more complex code that filters non-string-or-ints.

Comment: @SashSinha The OP wants to filter `int`s, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 'hello', 'world']
filtered_list = [x for x in my_list if (isinstance(x,str)) or ((isinstance(x,int)) and (x>2))]
print(filtered_list)
[3, 'hello', 'world']
```

Answer (score 1):

As a list comprehension:

```py
[x for x in my_list if not isinstance(x, int) or x > 2]
```

Reads as: Take all x which are either not integers or which are integers, but are larger than `2`. We leverage that `or` is short-circuiting, so `x > 2` (which would error for strings) will only be evaluated if `x` is an integer.

You might want to use [`isinstance(x, numbers.Number)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187185/how-can-i-check-if-my-python-object-is-a-number) to also deal with other number types.

I also find this quite readable using `filter`:

```py
list(filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, int) or x > 2, my_list))
```

Often you just need an iterator, and not a new list; you could save yourself the enclosing `list` then.

---

Note: Your example only contains strings and ints; this solution retains every non-integer value, including non-string values. If you also need to filter out other types, you could change the condition to `isinstance(x, str) or (isinstance(x, int) and x > 2)`. Again short circuiting makes sure you only compare `x` against `2` if `x` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

filtered_list = [x for x in my_list if type(x)==str or type(x)==int and x>2]

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

try use this:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 'hello', 'world']
threshold = 2

filtered_list = [x for x in my_list if isinstance(x, str) or (isinstance(x, int) and x > threshold)]

print(filtered_list)
```