# How to check for a function type in Python?

Tags: python, function, types

I've got a list of things, of which some can also be functions. If it is a function I would like to execute it. For this I do a type-check. This normally works for other types, like str, int or float. But for a function it doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> def f():
...     pass
... 
>>> type(f)
<type 'function'>
>>> if type(f) == function: print 'It is a function!!'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
>>>
```

Does anybody know how I can check for a function type?

Comment: You can also use try/except instead of checking for type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't check types, check actions. You don't actually care if it's a function (it might be a class instance with a `__call__` method, for example) - you just care if it can be called. So use `callable(f)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
import types

if type(f) == types.FunctionType: 
    print 'It is a function!!'
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `function` isn't a built-in type, a `NameError` is raised. If you want to check whether something is a function, use `hasattr`:

```
>>> hasattr(f, '__call__')
True
```

Or you can use `isinstance()`:

```
>>> from collections import Callable
>>> isinstance(f, Callable)
True
>>> isinstance(map, Callable)
True
```

Comment: `isinstance` is not good for `isinstance(map, types.FunctionType)` returns `False`. Builtin functions are different not to mention the callable class.

Comment: @zhangyangyu For built-in functions, you can use `inspect.isbuiltin`

Comment: There is `collections.Callable`. It works for buitlin functions too: `isinstance(map, collections.Callable)` returns `True`

Comment: @stalk - What's the difference between collections.Callable and simply callable (as suggested by DanielRoseman)?

Comment: @kramer65 well, i think it just another solution. `callable()` looks like more simplier.

Comment: @kramer65 I did some research, it looks like callable was considered deprecated, and was actually removed in python 3.0 as it was suggested to use collections.Callable. However, it was put back in in 3.1

Comment: @kramer65 `callable` is a built-in function. `collections.Callable` is [an abstract base class for classes that provide the __call__() method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Callable). I don't see any reason to use the latter for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

[collections.Callable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Callable) can be used:

```
import collections

print isinstance(f, collections.Callable)
```

Comment: And in new-ish Python 3 versions (I think it's 3.2+) `callable` is re-introduced as a shorthand for this.