# Python - No valuerror on int with isalpha

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is no ValueError raised on this try / except when isalpha should fail.

I know that isalpha returns false if given a number

```
In [9]: ans = input("Enter a Letter")
Enter a Letter4

In [10]: ans.isalpha()
Out[10]: False
```

How do I get the value error if they supply a number instead of a y or n? Because if the try is false shouldn't it stop being true and not print my trajectory?

```
import sys

v0 = float(input("What velocity would you like? "))
g = float(input("What gravity would you like? "))
t = float(input("What time decimal would you like? "))

print("""
    We have the following inputs.
       v0 is %d
       g is  %d
       t is  %d
    Is this correct? [Y/n]
""" % (v0, g, t))
while True:
    try:
        answer = input("\t >> ").isalpha()
        print(v0 * t - 0.5 * g * t ** 2)
    except ValueError as err:
        print("Not a valid entry", err.answer)
        sys.exit()
    finally:
            print("would you like another?")
            break
```

For example if the user types 5 not a y or n still gets an answer

```
$ python3 ball.py 
What velocity would you like? 2
What gravity would you like? 3
What time decimal would you like? 4

    We have the following inputs.
       v0 is 2
       g is  3
       t is  4
    Is this correct? [Y/n]

     >> 5
-16.0
would you like another?
```

Comment: As you've already stated, `isalpha()` returns `True | False`. Why would you expect it to raise a `ValueError`?

Comment: @SiHa                     from several SO example showing answer that if an int is false it will raise a valueError for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/8075959/461887. Figured the reverse would then be true

Comment: But that's completely different. In that situation, they are trying to cast a non-numeric string to an int, which raises an exception because it is not possible. Calling `'4'.isalpha()` will return `False` but no exception will be raised because *no exception has occurred* - the function call was successful. I would suggest reading up a bit more on `try...except` to fully understand the concept.

Comment: @SiHa          so is it possible to do the reverse which i was trying to cast an int to a string and get same failure or is the int special in that respect? Which will be where I have screwed up my intent.

Comment: But you are *not* trying to cast an int to a string, you are calling a library function to tell you if it is a letter of the alphabet. As mentioned below, it is generally a bad idea to use exceptions to control program flow. You have a boolean from your `isalpha()` call, use it in an `if` statement, and forget about exceptions here. P.S. if you *did* try to cast an int to a string, that would not raise an exception anyway  - `'4'` is a perfectly valid string :)

Comment: @SiHa          thanks, the example was contrived from a problem I had previously solved just to use and learn try and except I thought a user entering an int when a string was desired was a good use case for that. Ultimately not

Answer (score 3):

`except ValueError as err:` only happens when there is a ValueError thrown. The value of `answer` is `False`, but that is just an arbitrary boolean value, not an error.

See [`ValueError` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) for examples of things that are errors.

In your case, simply test:

```
answer = input("\t >> ")
if answer.isalpha():
    print(v0 * t - 0.5 * g * t ** 2)
    break
```

Comment: I searched SO before posting and seems a mixed opinion to whether one should prefer to use conditional logic versus try / except. In this case it was a contrived problem for me just to use try and except if a user didn't enter a "Y" or "y" I gave up and just tried to get an error if it wasn't a letter

Comment: `Explicit is better than implicit.` suggests that conditional logic should be preferred over `try / except`. Can you post a couple links where this is discussed.

Comment: Here is one question I have closed a few SO tabs off in posting, however one answer has 63 for try except and the other 61 for conditional  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2020598/461887  especially see some of the comments which are directing to use the try except as the preference

Comment: The one with 63 is catching an exception from an external function, not from the evaluation of a local variable. A function throwing an exception is actually preferred to it returning `None` to indicate special meaning, as per `Effective Python`. But that case is very different than evaluating a variable

Comment: @sayth in the case you mention, I favor the exception. The `simulate` function returns a boolean in normal exception, and the `except` catches unexpected failures.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should prefer to use normal control flow logic to handle a range of user input rather than raising/catching exceptions.

Comment: The print section works fine, it appears my inability to cast an int to string for failure and ValueError is my undoing. In testing for isalpha() I only received boolean.

Comment: Can you give an example of values for `v`, `g`, and `t`, and what is printed, when the user inputs a number? The statement `print(3 * '4' - 0.5 * 5 * '4' ** 2)`, for example, raises a `TypeError`.

Comment: I have it in my updated question, for with ints of 2 3 4 and returns -16.0

Comment: OK I misunderstood. I thought `t` referred to the user input.

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise the error yourself.  There is no exception raised by typing in something that you don't prefer:

```
try:
    answer = input("\t >> ").isalpha()
    if not answer:
        raise ValueError
    print(v0 * t - 0.5 * g * t ** 2)
except ValueError as err:
    print("Not a valid entry", err.answer)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: what do you think that `err.answer` will do?

Comment: I hadn't looked into it that deeply.  It won't print the value of answer

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer for clarity trying to provide a way to be more consistent and explicit with the treatment of *strings* and *int's*. By using *isinstance* I declare to a person reading my code explicitly what my values are to be hopefully improving readability.

```
answer = input("\t >> ")
if isinstance(int(answer), int) is True:
    raise ValueError("Ints aren't valid input")
    sys.exit()
elif isinstance(answer, str) is True:
        print(v0 * t - 0.5 * g * t ** 2)
else:
    print("Ok please ammend your entries")
```

Should I have differing requirements later this could easily be abstracted into a function, which because isinstance allows checking against multiple types increases flexibility.

**Reference** [How to properly use python's isinstance() to check if a variable is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11204870/461887)

```
def testSomething(arg1, **types):
    if isintance(arg1, [types]):
        do_something
```