# Splitting a list into numbers only

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function where it takes a list that contains both numbers and strings and returns only a list containing numbers. The code I have written is shown below, but it keeps throwing an error and I can’t understand what I have done wrong. Hope you can help.

```
lst = [99, 'no data', 95, 94, 'no data'] 

def foo(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if x.isdigit()] 

print(foo(lst))
```

Comment: `int` doesn't have the attribute `isdigit`, so you cannot call that to determine if it's a digit or not. Try something like: `[x for x in lst if isinstance(x, int)]`

Comment: please mention if you want to separate only `int` and `string` or you are looking to separate `string` which is numeric .. because in given example some are integer and others are strings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly use python's isinstance() to check if a variable is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204789/how-to-properly-use-pythons-isinstance-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-number)

Comment: ooo I see. Thanks so much for your help everyone, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [99, 'no data', 95, 94, 'no data']

def foo(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if isinstance(x, int)]

print(foo(lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [99, 'no data', 95, 94, 'no data'] 

def foo(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if isinstance(x,str)] 

print(foo(lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [99, 'no data', 95, 94, 'no data'] 

def isDigit(n):
    return type(n) is int
def foo(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if isDigit(x)] 

print(foo(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [99, 'no data', 95, 94, 'no data'] 

def foo(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if type(x)==int] 

print(foo(lst))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the questions. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, more useful for future visitors, and more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the `isdigit()` only works on `string`

```
lst = [99, 'no data', 95, 94, 'no data']

def foo(lst):
    return [lst[x] for x in range(0,len(lst)) if str(lst[x]).isdigit() ]


print(foo(lst))
```

Output:

```
[99, 95, 94]
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to check if each of the element's type is `int` or not. As mentioned in the comments, `isDigit` is not available for elements of type `int`.

```
lst = [99, 'no data', 95, 94, 'no data']
list=[]
def foo(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if type(x)==int]

print(foo(lst))
```

output:

```
[99, 95, 94]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the questions. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, more useful for future visitors, and more likely to attract upvotes.