# Check if value is zero or not null in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Often I am checking if a number variable `number` has a value with `if number` but sometimes the number could be zero. So I solve this by `if number or number == 0`.

Can I do this in a smarter way? I think it's a bit ugly to check if value is zero separately.

## Edit

I think I could just check if the value is a number with

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

but then I will still need to check with `if number and is_number(number)`.

Comment: Your title asks for `not None` or a number. Are you saying you have multiple types now?

Comment: Your `is_number()` test will work for strings with values convertible to integers. That's something entirely different.

Comment: See also [What is the most pythonic way to check if an object is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46324571/562769)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If `number` could be `None` *or* a number, and you wanted to include `0`, filter on `None` instead:

```
if number is not None:
```

If `number` can be any number of types, test for the *type*; you can test for just `int` or a combination of types with a tuple:

```
if isinstance(number, int):  # it is an integer
if isinstance(number, (int, float)):  # it is an integer or a float
```

or perhaps:

```
from numbers import Number

if isinstance(number, Number):
```

to allow for integers, floats, complex numbers, `Decimal` and `Fraction` objects.

Comment: But I do want my statement to evaluate as true if the value is not null OR the value is zero.

Comment: Of course. Thank you.. What if I'm only interested in knowing if it is a number? I've edited my question

Comment: @Jamgreen: then test for the **type** with `isinstance()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How do you get isinstance method?

Comment: @SamKahChiin: it isn't a method. It's a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Answer (score 18):

Zero and None both treated as same for if block, below code should work fine.

```
if number or number==0:
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

The simpler way:

```
h = ''
i = None
j = 0
k = 1
print h or i or j or k
```

Will print `1`

```
print k or j or i or h
```

Will print `1`

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT USE:

```
if number or number == 0:
    return true
```

this will check "number == 0" even if it is None.
You can check for None **and** if it's value is 0:

```
if number and number == 0:
    return true
```

Python checks the conditions from left to right:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it can be converted to decimal. If yes, then its a number

```
from decimal import Decimal

def is_number(value):
    try:
        value = Decimal(value)
        return True
    except:
        return False

print is_number(None)   // False
print is_number(0)      // True
print is_number(2.3)    // True
print is_number('2.3')  // True (caveat!)
```