# How to determine that a Python object is numeric?

Tags: python

What is the best way to determine if a Python object is numeric?
I'm using the following test

```
type(o) in [int, long, float, complex]
```

But I wonder if there is another way.

Comment: Sometimes you _do_ need such explicit tests, but it's nice to avoid them when possible so that you get the full benefits of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: The canonical duplicate for this question should really be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441358/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-number

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The preferred approach is to use [`numbers.Number`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number), which is

> The root of the numeric hierarchy. If you just want to check if an
>   argument *x* is a number, without caring what kind, use *isinstance(x,
>   Number*)

as shown below

```
In [1]: import numbers

In [2]: isinstance(1, numbers.Number)
Out[2]: True

In [3]: isinstance(1.0, numbers.Number)
Out[3]: True

In [4]: isinstance(1j, numbers.Number)
Out[4]: True
```

Also, `type(o) in [int, long, float, complex]` can be rewritten as

```
isinstance(o, (int, long, float, complex))
```

to make it more robust, as in able to detect subclasses of *int*, *long*, *float* and *complex*.

Comment: And of course `isinstance(o, numbers.Number)` is generally superior to `isinstance(o, (int, long, float, complex))` since it means that any object which claims to be some kind of number will pass the test.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) function.

> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof

Sample Usage

```
isinstance(o, (int, long, float, complex))
```