# Python: How to check the data type of key-value pair of an object?

Tags: python, object, types, arithmetic-expressions

I am creating a function to add the marks of each array(homework, quiz, test) inside an object(student1). There definitely arises errors as the code tries to add "Lloyd".
I want to check the *data-type* of *value* of "name" so as to carry the arithmetic operation only if the *value* of the *key* is number. Please Suggest.

```
student1 = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90, 97, 75, 92],
    "quiz": [88, 40, 94],
    "test": [75, 90]
}    

def eachSubjAverage(std):             
    for item in std:                        
        total = sum(std[item])   #totalling each marks
        std[item].append(total)     

        average_no = total/(len(std[item])-1) #averaging the marks
        std[item].append(average_no) 

eachSubjAverage(student1)
```

Comment: Note that dictionaries are not ordered, so appending in order will not be the order you expect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary

Comment: @Tim : the code is appending to lists, not dicts - FWIW, dicts dont have an "append" method. It's still a bad idea to append average and total to the marks, but for a different reason...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An obvious case of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Your real problem is a wrong data structure that stores heterogenous informations (the student's name and it's marks) the same way. The RightSolution(tm) is to use a better data structure, ie:

```
student1 = {
    "personal_infos" : {
        "name": "Lloyd",
    },
    "marks": {
        "homework": [90, 97, 75, 92],
        "quiz": [88, 40, 94],
        "test": [75, 90]
    },
    "totals": {}
    "averages": {}
  }
```

}

Once you have this, you don't have to test whether you have a string or num as value:

```
def eachSubjAverage(student):             
    for subject, marks in student["marks"].items():                        
        total = sum(marks)   #totalling each marks
        student["totals"][subject] = total     
        average = total / (len(marks))
        student["averages"][subject] = average
```

Note that you could layout your data differently, ie per subject:

```
student1 = {
    "personal_infos" : {
        "name": "Lloyd",
    },
    "subjects": {
        "homework": {
            "marks" : [90, 97, 75, 92],
            "total" : None,
            "average" : None
            }, 
        "quiz": {
            "marks" : [88, 40, 94],
            "total" : None,
            "average" : None
            }, 
        "test": {
            "marks" : [75, 90],
            "total" : None,
            "average" : None
            }, 
        },
 }


def eachSubjAverage(student):             
    for subject, data in student["subjects"].items():                        
        total = sum(data["marks"])   #totalling each marks
        data["total"] = total     
        average = total / (len(data["marks"]))
        data["average"] = average
```

Note that if you don't have the option to fix the data structure (external data or else), you *still* don't want to rely on type-checking (which is brittle at best) - you want to test the key itself, either by whitelisting the subjects names or blacklisting the "non-subjects" names, ie:

```
# blacklist non-subjects
NON_SUBJECTS = ("name",)

def your_func(student):
    for key, value in student.items():
        if key in NON_SUBJECTS:
            continue
        compute_stuff_here()
```

Oh and yes: adding the total and average in the marks list is also a good way to shoot yourself in the foot - once it's done, you can't tell wether the last two "marks" are marks or (total, average).

Comment: Thank you Bruno for providing me the fundamentally proper approach on managing (heterogeneous) informations inside an object. I am now aware of the xy nature of my question. I will be following this approach as it seems the most cogent technique. 

You provided the solution for the situation where I don't have the option to fix the data structure. I couldn't understand the for and if statements. Please pardon my basic queries. Could you provide me the solution in reference to my question? Thanks for your kind support!

Comment: "I couldn't understand the for and if statements." Well this is fairlay basic Python stuff - what is it that you don't understand exactly ?

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I do understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in std:
    if isinstance(std[item],list):
        total = sum(std[item])
```

if you want to make sure that the elements in the list is of type `int`, then

```
for item in std:
    if isinstance(std[item],list) and all(isinstance(e,int) for e in student1[item]):
        total = sum(std[item])
```

learn about [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) method

Comment: And then someday the dict grows a list of ints that are not marks, and they are treated as such by the code.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers that's not my problem is it? I'm simply trying to answer the question. Am I suppose to predict the future?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods to check the value of the data. `try/except` construction looks bulky, but there are more shorter ways.

First of all you can use function `type`, which returns you type of the object:

```
>>> type(student1['name']) == str
True
>>> type(student1['test']) == list
True
```

Or, to use a very simple trick. Multiplying any object to zero returns an empty object or 0 if `int`:

```
>>> student1['name']*0 == ""
True
>>> student1['test']*0 == []
True
>>> student1['test'][1]*0 == 0
True
```

Comment: `isinstance(obj, cls)` is usually a better choice than testing type equality. Oh and yes also, `type` is actually a class, not a function.

Comment: @Sdwdaw: Thanks for the solution. I learned that this isn't the best approach. Though, it have some caveats, it solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can check whether the value is iterable:

```
hasattr(std[item], '__iter__')
```

and then check that each member is a [Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441358/python-most-pythonic-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-number):

```
all( map ( lambda x: isinstance(x,numbers.Number), std[item] ) )
```

Comment: Are strings not iterable?

Comment: It depends on the version of Python, I expanded my answer

Comment: Still trying to fix the wrong issue. The real issue is an incorrect datastructure that mixes student's personal infos ("name") and subjects marks...

Answer (score -2):

You could use a `try except`:

```
for item in std:
    try:
        total = sum(std[item])
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Comment: Then one day someone puts a string in the marks (which is an error), and the code silently passes over instead of crashing loudly - as it should.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ahh, fair point. Your answer does work much better :)