# How do I ignore a string in a function that accepts multiple arguments in python?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm trying to answer a python programming question:

> Write a function `operate_nums` that computes the product of all other input arguments and returns its negative if the keyword argument `negate` (default `False`) is `True` or just the product if `negate` is `False`. The function should ignore non-numeric arguments.

So far I have the following code:

```
def operate_nums(*args):
     product = 1
     negate = True

     for i in args:
         product = product * i

     if negate == True:
         return product * -1
     return product
```

If I input a set of numbers and strings in my argument, how will code it so that my code ignores the strings?

Comment: FWIW, `negate` is supposed to be a *keyword argument*, so: `def operate_nums(*args, negate = False): ...`

Comment: To ignore non-numeric values in your for loop you can use isinstance(i, Number) to check if i is a number before attempting to multiply as explained [What is the most pythonic way to check if an object is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441358/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `isinstance` that lets you check the type of your variable. As pointed in one of the comments by @DarrylG, you can use `Number` as an indicator whether an argument is the one you want to multiply by

```
from numbers import Number

def operate_nums(*args, negate=False):
    product = 1

    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, Number): # check if the argument is numeric
            product = product * arg

    if negate == True:
            return product * -1

    return product
```

Comment: thank you so much!! i didn't know that you can pass booleans in function arguments

Comment: This only ignores strings.  You could use `if isinstance(arg, Number): product = product * arg` where Number is defined by `from numbers import Number`.  Then any type of non-numeric (such as None, [], {}, etc.) is ignroed.